# Choosing which CCScene to be run

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm new to `Cocos2Dx`. I'm trying to create a game which has 3-4 modes. I've created the menu using UIKit (iOS specific code). Now I need to call the corresponding `CCScene` Class. I've implemented them separately. But I don't know how to present them.

On `button1` press I do the following:

```
    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Init the EAGLView
    EAGLView *__glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame: [_window bounds]
                                     pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                     depthFormat: GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
                              preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                      sharegroup: nil
                                   multiSampling: NO
                                 numberOfSamples: 0];

    [__glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    // Use RootViewController manage EAGLView
    _viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    _viewController.view = __glView;

    // Set RootViewController to window
    if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
    {
        // warning: addSubView doesn't work on iOS6
        [_window addSubview: _viewController.view];
    }
    else
    {
        // use this method on ios6
        [_window setRootViewController:_viewController];
    }

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true];

    cocos2d::CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();
```

This inturn calls `AppDelegate.cpp` and presents the mode 1 of the game like so:

```
    // initialize director
    CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

    pDirector->setOpenGLView(pEGLView);

    // turn on display FPS

    // set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
    pDirector->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);

    // create a scene. it's an autorelease object
    CCScene *pScene = ClassicModeLayer::scene();

    // run
    pDirector->runWithScene(pScene);
```

Here the mode one is called `ClassicMode`. Now how do I press `button2` and call another `CCScene` for arcade mode or some other mode? How do I pass the button press events to `AppDelegate.cpp`?

Comment: You are only hurting yourself by trying to do this.  There is really no benefit.  There are plenty of tutorials out there about how to set up a menu and such in cocos2d-x so I suggest that you try that.  Viper's comment is valid, you lose the only benefit of cocos2d-x (cross platform ability...to an extent)

Comment: Alright. I'll make use of Cocos2d-x to create the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add mode selection screen by cocos2dx i.e by CCScene itself,

Just add mode selection scene first then load scene according to selected mode.

Comment: I know that should have been the right approach. But like I said, I'm just starting off with Cocos2d-x. So I created the menu using UIKit as I'm more comfortable using that. So are you saying its not possible this way? Say, to pass a variable or something?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/11655 this is about how to call a obj-c function from a cpp file by using bridge file i.e .mm file, you just have to inverse the approach. but still i will suggest you to create mode selection screen by using cocos2dx, otherwise your code won't be cross platform as you have to do the sane for other platforms too, rest is your choice how you want it to be.